# Electron doesn't show reload and toggledevtools menus

Tags: electron

I'm starting from the [template menu specified in the documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/) which includes

```
{
    label: 'View',
    submenu: [
      {
        role: 'reload'
      },
      {
        role: 'toggledevtools'
      },
      {
        type: 'separator'
      },
```

but when I run the application, this is what I see:

[image]

Any ideas why those menu items are not appearing (they also don't work)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the project I'm working on was using Electron 1.3.X instead of 1.4 and this was because it was using [grunt-download-electron](https://github.com/electron-archive/grunt-download-electron), which is old and probably obsolete. That meant that despite the version declared in package.json, an older version of Electron was being downloaded.